# Only allow text field to contain certain string values

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I'm new to Prisma - I'm using it with a PostgreSQL database.

I have a table in my database that has a string field - I'd like, if possible, for that string field to only accept certain values: for example, "foo" and "bar", and if someone tried to insert any other string, e.g. "blah", it wouldn't be accepted.

Is this possible?

Comment: If not - I'm looking for this functionality because the item I am modeling can belong to any one of several categories - Category A, Category B, Category C, etc. So I was looking to model that with a "Category" field that could only have the strings "Category A", "Category B", or "Category C" - is there some more preferable way to model this relationship?

Comment: Do not add information in comments. Instead, [edit] your question so that it becomes part of the question itself and can be seen. Comments are transitory and can be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible using the [Prisma enum API](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#enum), check the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#enum) to see how to properly use it for your requirement